# Why `git log` shows different dates?

Tags: git, date, github, formatting

I'm trying to change date of several commits.
The sequence of commands looks like :

```
git checkout HEAD~2
git checkout -b new_branch
git merge version new_branch
git checkout master # switch back
git reset --hard HEAD~2

# block of creating commits with different date
git cherry-pick -n -m 1 hash_of_HEAD~1
git commit -m 'msg' --date="my_date"
git cherry-pick -n -m 1 hash_of_HEAD
git commit -m 'msg' --date="my_date"
```

When I run

```
git log
```

I see the date `my_date`, but if the `git log` uses option `--format` with some date template, for example

```
git log --format="%ci"
```

I see the date when I'd commited this commit.

Example:

- real date = 18.11.2021 10:00:00 +0000
- new date = 18.11.2021 11:00:00 +0000
- date when commit was written = 18.11.2021 18:00:00 +0000

`git log` - will show 11:00

`git log --format="%ci"` - will show 18:00

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Looks like a confusion between `authordate` and `committerdate`. Try comparing with `git log --format="%ai"`. However, this is pure output. What is it you wanted to "change"?

Comment: Thanks, it works as expected.